# Is there a portable way to put a timeout on flock()?

Tags: php, timeout, flock

[`flock()`](http://php.net/flock) is PHP's **portable** advisory file locking function. They explicitly promote that it even works under windows:

> flock() allows you to perform a simple reader/writer model which can be used on virtually every platform (including most Unix derivatives and even Windows).

I'd like to put an also **portable** timeout on a blocking `flock()` (and no busy waiting work around with the `LOCK_NB` option). In UNIX this can simply be achieved with setting an alarm which would send a `SIGALRM`:

```
pcntl_signal(SIGALRM, function() {});
pcntl_alarm(3);
try {
    if (!flock($handle, LOCK_EX)) {
        throw new \Exception("Timeout");
    }
} finally {
    pcntl_alarm(0);
    pcntl_signal_dispatch();
    pcntl_signal(SIGALRM, SIG_DFL);
}
```

Is there a portable way to put a timeout on a blocking `flock()`? If so, how?

Comment: `LOCK_NB` + a loop + `usleep`?

Comment: > and no busy waiting work around with the LOCK_NB option

Comment: http://php.net/flock

Comment: @zerkms I'm sure he already looked there … The actual answer is that there is no way to do that portably in PHP. Windows has an alarm functionality, but it's not exposed via any extension in PHP.

Comment: @bwoebi well, they decided play pedantic. So did I - everything `flock` can do is explained on that page (or in php sources). PS: it is weird one even want to terminate the process instead of handling it gracefully (even with a busy waiting loop)

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch Anyway, you'll have to mess around with a separate process in order to have it deliver an interrupting signal to your program after timeout passed. There's no other way…

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch "Where do you read on that page how to put a timeout under UNIX" --- it's literally sending a signal. Unblocking is just a side effect. If you're fine killing the current process - then simply `exec` a command that would kill the current PID after a timeout.

Comment: It is not "within the same process", it is scheduled as a kernel timer.

Comment: The comments are getting far to chatty and drifting away from the actual question. But I'd like to add that you don't have to terminate the process in UNIX. `flock()` will indicate its failure with the return value. And to prevent termination one could install a noop signal handler for `SIGALRM`. No `exec()` or other process is needed for this. And if there's no portable option, then I will simply accept the first "No, there's no portable timeout"  answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that there is any way to do this on Windows without a busy wait / polling loop.

PHP implements [`flock`](http://php.net/flock) on windows using [`LockFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365203(v=vs.85).aspx) (see [`flock_compat.c:132`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/c8aa6f3a9a3d2c114d0c5e0c9fdd0a465dbb54a5/ext/standard/flock_compat.c#L132)). As you can see from these similar questions, there is no way to set a timeout on `LockFileEx` or to cancel a process waiting for a `LockFileEx` request (i.e. there is no equivalent to the `SIGALRM` signal for this use-case):

1. [LockFile with timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809035/lockfile-with-timeout) (asked 2011)

> Q) If I want to wait for file-lock with timeout, how would I go about it?
>
> ...
>
> A) write a small loop to check the return code

2. ["LockFileEx can't time out it just hangs"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel/4sCVlrkweAo) from `microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel` mailing list, 1997

> Q) Does anyone know of a way to get LockFileEx to time out ?
>
> ...
>
> A) you can only have it fail imemdiately, sleep, and loop back
>   until you reach some retry limit.